# Html Element Load File With AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

So I want to load a file with AngularJS code in it.

This `index.html` is the master page (template) which will load the child page:

```
<body class="np">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-controller.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="pageContainer"> 
    </div>
</body>
```

The child content will be loaded inside `#pageContainer`. This is how I load it:

```
$("#pageContainer").load("/views/" + path + ".html", function(data) { }
```

This is the child page:

```
<div class="row" id="pageContent">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1 contenteditable="true">{{title}}</h1>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="note-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/js/pages/edit-note.js"></script>
```

And this is my `edit-note.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('ctrl', ctrl);
ctrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$window"];

function ctrl($scope, $http, $window) {
   $scope.title = "Title";
}

var pageContent = $('#pageContent');
angular.bootstrap(pageContent, 'app');
```

I tried to bootstrap the content after loaded using `angular.bootstrap()` but it is not working. The `{{title}}` does not change from the `$scope.title = "Title"`.

How can I load it correctly?

Comment: I'm sure jQuery is not the best way to load a view in Angular.

Comment: I'm not sure myself. I am using Cordova in this case. Actually I want to have just 1 page, then each navigation should just change the page content, rather than changing the Url into another page. I just cannot figure it out how to load each content with different AngularJS script attach to each content.